# Selenium example using Node.js from MDN not working?

Tags: node.js, selenium

I have been trying to work with the Selenium example from this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/Your_own_automation_environment.

I have done the following steps:

1. Set up a new npm project
2. Install the selenium webdriver using `npm install selenium-webdriver`
3. I've also gotten the GeckoDriver and ChromeDriver and added them to my PATH.
4. Then I created a local copy of the example google_test.js (shown below) and ran it using the command `node google_test`.

   var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
       By = webdriver.By,
       until = webdriver.until;

   var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
       .forBrowser('firefox')
       .build();

   driver.get('http://www.google.com');

   driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');

   driver.sleep(1000).then(function() {
     driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys(webdriver.Key.TAB);
   });

   driver.findElement(By.name('btnK')).click();

   driver.sleep(2000).then(function() {
     driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
       if(title === 'webdriver - Google Search') {
         console.log('Test passed');
       } else {
         console.log('Test failed');
       }
     });
   });

   driver.quit();

**My problem is that for me, the example above only opens a new Firefox instance, and immediately closes without performing any actions.**

After running the command `node google_test` I get the error messages below:

```
(node:23652) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SessionNotCreatedError: Tried to run command without establishing a connection
    at Object.throwDecodedError (/home/hanbin/programman/webdev/selenium-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:550:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/home/hanbin/programman/webdev/selenium-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:542:13)
    at Executor.execute (/home/hanbin/programman/webdev/selenium-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:468:26)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:178:7)
(node:23652) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:23652) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:23652) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SessionNotCreatedError: Tried to run command without establishing a connection
    at Object.throwDecodedError (/home/hanbin/programman/webdev/selenium-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:550:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/home/hanbin/programman/webdev/selenium-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:542:13)
    at Executor.execute (/home/hanbin/programman/webdev/selenium-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:468:26)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:178:7)
(node:23652) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:23652) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SessionNotCreatedError: Tried to run command without establishing a connection
    at Object.throwDecodedError (/home/hanbin/programman/webdev/selenium-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:550:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/home/hanbin/programman/webdev/selenium-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:542:13)
    at Executor.execute (/home/hanbin/programman/webdev/selenium-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:468:26)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:178:7)
(node:23652) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
(node:23652) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SessionNotCreatedError: Tried to run command without establishing a connection
    at Object.throwDecodedError (/home/hanbin/programman/webdev/selenium-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:550:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/home/hanbin/programman/webdev/selenium-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:542:13)
    at Executor.execute (/home/hanbin/programman/webdev/selenium-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:468:26)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:178:7)
(node:23652) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 5)
(node:23652) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SessionNotCreatedError: Tried to run command without establishing a connection
    at Object.throwDecodedError (/home/hanbin/programman/webdev/selenium-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:550:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/home/hanbin/programman/webdev/selenium-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:542:13)
    at Executor.execute (/home/hanbin/programman/webdev/selenium-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:468:26)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:178:7)
(node:23652) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 6)
```

My package.json file is:

```
{
  "name": "selenium-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "", 
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },  
  "author": "", 
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.1"
  }
}
```

Could anyone please assist me?